# Internet Explorer 9 and Chrome don't handle set-cookie headers

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome, cookies, internet-explorer-9

I am testing my website which works fine with Iron, Firefox and Opera, now using Internet Explorer 9, and Chrome. It sets two important cookies in every browser, except for IE9 and Chrome. It seems the set-cookie headers are ignored by these browsers. Until I lowered security and privacy settings, Facebook's cookies were missing too in Internet Explorer (except for cookies from skype.com, there weren't any cookies at all inside IE).

The cookies are set for the domain modern-iq.appspot.com (the alpha version of this project is accessible at http://modern-iq.appspot.com). It doesn't contain underscores and it looks standard-compliant to me.

Independent of the actual path, I always choose "/" for my cookies.
The domain is always modern-iq.appspot.com (no cross-domain cookies). There are no iframes.

UPDATE: I did the following tests:

work

- Iron 12.0.750.0 (88853) on Ubuntu (64-bit): cookies work
- Firefox 6.0 on Ubuntu (64-bit): cookies work
- Firefox 3.6.13 on Windows XP: cookies work
- Firefox (unknown version) on Windows 7: cookies work

don't work

- Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7: cookies don't work
- Chrome 13.0.782.112 m on Windows XP: cookies don't work

UPDATE: Request logs of failing Chrome and working Iron:

- [requestlog-chrome.har](http://ubuntuone.com/p/1Bio/) (cookies ignored)
- [requestlog-chrome.txt](http://ubuntuone.com/p/1Bil/) (cookies ignored)
- [requestlog-iron.har](http://ubuntuone.com/p/1Bip/) (cookies kept)
- [requestlog-iron.txt](http://ubuntuone.com/p/1Bim/) (cookies kept)

The questionable cookies are fb_user and fb_access_token at the end of the request chain.

[image: All cookies are accepted, but IE9 doesn't send them]

set_cookie calls (Python):

```
set_cookie(self.response, FACEBOOK_USER_COOKIE_NAME, str(profile["id"]), domain='modern-iq.appspot.com',
                   expires=time.time() + COOKIE_EXPIRY_SPAN) #30 * 86400)
set_cookie(self.response, FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME, str(access_token), domain='modern-iq.appspot.com',
                   expires=time.time() + COOKIE_EXPIRY_SPAN) #30 * 86400)
```

set_cookie (Python):

```
def set_cookie(response, name, value, domain=None, path="/", expires=None):
    """Generates and signs a cookie for the give name/value"""
    for domain in domain, : #'localhost':
        logging.info('DOING COOKIE OF DOMAIN '+repr(domain)+'...')
        timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
        value = base64.b64encode(value)
        signature = cookie_signature(value, timestamp)
        cookie = Cookie.BaseCookie()
        cookie[name] = "|".join([value, timestamp, signature])
        cookie[name]["path"] = path
        if domain: cookie[name]["domain"] = domain
        if expires:
            cookie[name]["expires"] = email.utils.formatdate(
                expires, localtime=False, usegmt=True)
        response.headers._headers.append(("Set-Cookie", cookie.output()[12:]))
```

Comment: I don't think the problem itself is Facebook-related at all. It is a Cookie problem.

Comment: I added a screenshot of IE's Privacy Report. It shows that all cookies are accepted. But if this is the case, why doesn't IE send them??

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a P3P header that reflects the privacy policies related to the cookie.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/06/05/understanding-internet-explorer-cookie-controls.aspx

Comment: There is no special privacy policy related to my cookies. For testing purposes, I lowered all security and privacy settings in IE. But it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: My Test App is outside an Iframe. There isn't any.

Comment: It's not about IFRAMES-- IE requires P3P headers for cross-origin cookies. You should revise your question to FULLY describe your design, including what code runs where.

Comment: The design isn't complicated. Everything runs on modern-iq.appspot.com. No iframes, no cross-origin. Single-domain.

Comment: Please provide a network capture (www.fiddler2.com) or alter your demo page such that it does not require people who want to help you to expose their network and wall to you.

Comment: I added request logs (HAR/TXT) to my question, in order to compare a working request sequence (in this case using Iron) and a failing request sequence (in this case Chrome).

Comment: Alas, Chrome apparently doesn't generate legal .HAR files (as they don't load into HAR viewing tools), making those files less than useful.

Comment: In the text log, your Set-Cookie header is badly malformed. Your server is either sending junk or Chrome's logging is broken.

Set-Cookie: fb_user=MTAwMDAwMzcxMzk4ODIz|1313841932|a49751f167cccf5b241e887486512c21f0ef9f49; Domain=modern-iq.appspot.com; expires=Sat, 20 Aug 2011 12:08:52 GMT; Path=/\nfb_access_token=MTQ4OTczMDcxODUyMTc0fDIuQVFBMGxwbHgtNHBuN3dVUi4zNjAwLjEzMTM4NDg4MDAuMS0xMDAwMDAzNzEzOTg4MjN8QmZPWUZjaC1MUzMzMTVTY0hGR1NlbDZ4VnRz|1313841932|438f89cddf730fac7aced5abec2169dfd23a7f82; Domain=modern-iq.appspot.com; expires=Sat, 20 Aug 2011 12:08:52 GMT; Path=/